# SVN move broke my build path?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, compilation

I have a very puzzling problem. I adjusted my SVN folders, creating trunk and tags folders. Then, when I went back to my project in Eclipse, now I have a compile error in my test class. It can't resolve the import statement that imports the class being tested into the test class. Any idea why this might have happened?

-Edit in response to comment:The exact compile error is

```
The import <class name> cannot be resolved
```

The exact changes I made in SVN were to create 2 new folders, one called trunk, one called tags, then I used the eclipse/svn rename/move command to move the project to the trunk folder. I then used the eclipse/svn Switch to another branch/tag/revision, and then tried Update to HEAD. I also tried a maven:clean build, to see if that made any difference, and it did not.

Comment: Give us a clue to the error message you're getting, or exactly what you tweaked in your repository? Also, did you do a new checkout or a `svn switch` to the new URL? Is this an _ant_ build via Eclipse, or the Eclipse automated build?

Comment: Probably a silly question, but I'll throw it out there... Is the class in question definitely under version control?  Maybe you added it in your working copy but never did an svn add and/or commit?

Comment: It sounds to me that you may have screwed up your build path.

Comment: @jahroy: The class in question is definitely under version control.

Comment: @robthewolf: Yes, it's apparent the build path is screwed up. My question is why would reorganizing the svn folders screw up the build path?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I still don't understand what happened, but I ran Maven:Update Project Configuration, and that fixed the problem.